# Collations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, collation

There is a table with the following stucture:

[image: Structure of table]

Here are the data in this table:

[image: Records in this table]

Ok, let's try the following:

```
SELECT
LOWER(md5_upper_bin), 
LOWER(md5_upper_ge_ci), 
UPPER(md5_lower_bin),
UPPER(md5_lower_ge_ci) 
FROM qwew
```

The result is:

[image: Result of experimental query]


**The question:** why the postfix `_bin` have been ignored? According to [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html), we can say that `_bin` affects to such functions like LOWER and UPPER too (and make them not working because binary-type collaction is used in these fields). But we've got another results in practice. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHAR` and `VARCHAR` store [*nonbinary* strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html), not *binary* strings. You have to change the actual column type to `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` for the `_bin` collation to affect `UPPER` and `LOWER` functions applied to data within them.